# Big Endian Hex Number conversation

Tags: java, math, hex

I have the following 4 bytes of Hex String (**38 01 02 00**) and the expected output is (**201.38**) Decimal, Like the first input is reversed.
If (**89 00 00 00**) is given then the expected outcome would be (**0.89**)

I don't know the mathematical name of this conversation.

1. I have tried converting Big-endian to little-endian but the outcome has failed with (00020138).
2. I have tried writing a simple method but the outcome is still wrong (1492992770)

```
int htonl(final int value) {
        return ByteBuffer
                .allocate(4)
                .putInt(value).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .getInt(0);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does 201.38 mean? A number in decimal notation with two fractional digits? Or some dotted groups of numbers like in IP addresses? Or still something else? Btút both of my guesses contradict your method's result type being integer.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff decimal notation with two fractional digits hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be BCD encoding (Binary Coded Decimal) where each 4-byte group represents one decimal place.

And the byte-order is little endian - it's beginning with the least significant byte.

All I see suggests that the decimal point is in a fixed position, but that's just a guess.

So, the result of your first try comes close. Just divide it by 100, and you're done.

Comment: thank you for your time and clarifying its BCD encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the help of @Ralf Kleberhoff

1. I reversed the hex input first
2. Divided the output with 100

```
public static String reverse(final String originalHex) {

        final int lengthInBytes = originalHex.length() / 2;
        final char[] chars = new char[lengthInBytes * 2];
        for (int index = 0; index < lengthInBytes; index++) {
            final int reversedIndex = lengthInBytes - 1 - index;
            chars[reversedIndex * 2] = originalHex.charAt(index * 2);
            chars[reversedIndex * 2 + 1] = originalHex.charAt(index * 2 + 1);
        }
        return new String(chars);
}
```

```
final float f = Float.parseFloat(reverse("89000000"));
System.out.println(f / 100);
```

3. Given input is 89000000 and result was 0.89 which was expected.